# run error when follow struts2 tutorial

Tags: struts2, weblogic

I am starting struts2 java web application and start with initial according to below URL tutorial.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_environment_setup.htm

I am using struts-2.5.10.1 with weblogic server in eclipse neon. When run, it has below error. Please help

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/velocity/tools/view/ToolboxManager;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:75)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.velocity.tools.view.ToolboxManager
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1026)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Comment: I find that this is due to classpath issue in setting in maven build path. I have deleted jars from webInf/lib/*.jar unless spring release jar remain. then maven update and successfully publish to localhost weblogic server.

Comment: But now when I type in url . localhost:7001/application/ . it has below error.

Comment: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/application]  --> Please help

Comment: namespace `/` name is empty. what do you want is unclear.

Comment: If you have a new error then it's a new question. The error you posted is caused by missing dependencies. The new error could be caused by just about anything, but probably looking at the startup logs would answer the question.